# setLayoutParams of a layout inside a Fragment from an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an Activity that has many fragment inside. When on a particular fragment I inflate a menu and when clicking on the inflated MenuItem I should call a method of the Fragment class that change the layout params of a Constraint Layout inside the fragment. The problem is that I get a NPE on the Constraint Layout I'm trying to change.

These are the methods I'm trying to call:

```
public void searcherOpen() {
    searchLayout.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    searchText.setFocusable(true);
}
public void searcherClose() {
    searchLayout.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
    searchText.setFocusable(false);
}
```

These are the MenuItem that are calling the methods:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.patient_fragment_menu, menu);
        final MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        final MenuItem close_search = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search_close);
        search.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                patientFragment.searcherOpen();
                search.setVisible(false);
                close_search.setVisible(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        close_search.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                patientFragment.searcherClose();
                search.setVisible(true);
                close_search.setVisible(false);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This is how I define the fragment inside the activity in onCreate:

```
patientFragment = (PatientFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("patientFragment");
```

And this is the error:

```
06-06 14:52:23.314 3682-3682/com.medishare.zeeromed E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.medishare.zeeromed, PID: 3682
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.medishare.zeeromed.fragments.PatientFragment.searcherOpen()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.medishare.zeeromed.DrawerActivity$3.onMenuItemClick(DrawerActivity.java:255)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:959)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:623)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:154)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22393)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, and obviously, this line code is not finding any fragment:

```
patientFragment = (PatientFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("patientFragment");
```

Secondly, when you try to find a fragment with `findFragmentByTag` you should always verify if the fragment exists, i.e., is not null

```
if(patientFragment != null) { patientFragment.myMethod(); }
```

Third, you also should verify if your fragment is Added to the activity, or you might end up in some other kind of NPE

```
if(patientFragment != null && patientFragment.isAdded()){ patientFragment.myMethod(); }
```

Finally, and probably the reason why you are getting this error lies where you create your fragment, or in this case, how you create it. I assume you are creating it inside you `Activity` which extends `FragmentActivity`, therefore you should be using `getSupportFragmentManager()` to create it. In other words, to retrieve the fragment you should also call `getSupportFragmentManager` like @CODER pointed out:

```
patientFragment = (PatientFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("patientFragment");
if(patientFragment != null && patientFragment.isAdded()){ 
    patientFragment.myMethod(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on stackTrace which you provide looks like your `PatientFragment` is `null` when you want to call `searcherOpen()`.
So you need to instantiate it first and then call that method.
This call:

```
patientFragment = (PatientFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("patientFragment");
```

is wrong, you should create it throught `newInstance()` call and add it to an activity using `FragmentManager`, please read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) arcticle for related questions

Answer (score 0):

try getSuportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()